# How can i read an print the values from the text file

Tags: groovy

I have data in the text file.

```
M10 M2GBXR100A.PGM 8.00000000 3.0000000 3.00000000 2545.07500000sec 0.0
```

I am trying to read and print the text file data but how can just get the individual data.
I have used

```
File file = new File("C:/File/stat_l15.txt")
    printn  file.text

String Name = file.text.substring(0, file.text.indexOf(' '))
```

By this I am able to retrieve  **M10** but how can I get **M2GBXR100A**

Finally I need the output as

```
Name : M10
pg_name : M2GBXR100A.PGM
right : 8.00000000 
left : 3.0000000
```

these data i am saving in a table !!

Answer (score 4):

Since your file is delimited by spaces, you can use [Split](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.html#split(java.lang.String)):

```
File file = new File("C:/File/stat_l15.txt")
println file.text

List values = file.text.split(' ')

println "Name: ${values[0]}"
println "pg_name: ${values[1]}"
println "right: ${values[2]}"
println "left : ${values[3]}"
```